# Passing File Objects with Django

Tags: python, django, parse-platform

I am attempting to retrieve a file and then upload it to Parse.com by submitting via POST.  My HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <form action="" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
     <fieldset>
       <input type="file" name="fileselect" id="fileselect" /></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="myFile" id="myFile" />
       <input id="uploadbutton" type="submit" value="Upload to Parse" />
     </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```

And using the following function to retrieve the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var file;

    // Set an event listener on the Choose File field.
    $('#fileselect').bind("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      // Our file var now holds the selected file
      file = files[0];
      document.getElementById('myFile').value = file;
    });
  });
</script>
```

However, this "myFile" field is not posting the file as an object nor does it jive with the Parse API documentation, which appears to be looking for a file path name, which I don't think I can pull from an unknown machine.

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/files/pic.jpg', open('myPicture.jpg','rb').read(), {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
 })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

This seems like it would be a common use case but the only documentation I found was for ajax, which I would prefer not to use because it exposes my API credentials https://www.parse.com/questions/uploading-files-to-parse-using-javascript-and-the-rest-api.

I am not sure what is the best way to handle the file... if there's a way to handle within the Django framework or if I need to convert to JSON.  And, even when the file object is captured, I'm not clear on how to use the Parse.com API with the file object.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it turns out that the answer is pretty straightforward.  Using the "Basic File Upload" documentation from the Django website: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/ and replacing

```
open('myPicture.jpg', 'rb').read()
```

in the Parse documentation (referenced in the question above) with

```
request.FILES['file']
```

I was able to successfully upload the file to Parse.  No javascript necessary.